# Create a variable in controller to order by

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form where a 3 of the user inputs have numbers (week1,2 and 3). I'd like to create a variable in my controller that would add the fields together.

i.e score = student.week1 + student.week2 + student.week3

I would then like to order the students on the `students.index.html.erb` page by the highest score. Part of the issue is my index page does not have a student.id until i go to the show or edit page etc

My student model:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{fname.parameterize}-#{lname.parameterize}"
  end
end
```

My Student controller

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @pagy, @students = pagy(Student.all, page: params[:page], items: 16)
    @students.order([:week1_score] + [:week2_score] + [:week3_score])
  end

  def new
    @student = Student.new
  end
end
```

I have tried creating a

```
  def score
    week1_score = @student.week1_score
    week2_score = @student.week2_score
    week3_score = @student.week3_score
    
    week1_score + week2_score + week3_score
  end
```

But i'm guessing the user_id is whats holding me back. Aside from the ordering, i'd still like to know the score of each student. Thanks

Comment: Can't you get the user id from `current_user`?  Are you using Devise or some other method of logging in and authenticating users?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What controller and action does this form submit to? What does that controller action look like? What does your `Student` model look like?

Comment: Yeah i'm using devise. The student table has the `user_id` and the `student.id`

Comment: @jvillian i've added my model and controller. My question is how to make a variable that can add three form fields together so i can then use this variable to order by (variable) on the index page, basically showing the best students first.

Comment: Where is the controller and action your form submits to? Also, you say `StudentsController`, but the class name is `DriversController`. Why not just create a `score` column in your `Students` table, set it in your `create` action, and then do `Students.all.order(score: :desc)`?

Comment: Sorry typo...should be StudentsController.

Comment: Okay. But what about the rest of my comment?

Comment: Yeah i am trying it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're approaching the problem completely wrong from the get go.

If the students table has the columns `week1_score`, `week2_score`, `week3_score` you should add them together in situ so that you can order the records in the database.

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  def index
    @students = Student.select(
      'students.*',
      '(students.week1_score + students.week2_score + students.week3_score) AS total_score'
    ).order(:total_score)
  end
  ...
end
```

Your attempt:

```
.order([:week1_score] + [:week2_score] + [:week3_score])
```

is actually a really bad equivalent to calling:

```
.order(:week1_score, :week2_score, :week3_score)
```

This will order by the three columns - not by the total.

Comment: Thanks @max. I'm still quite new to Ruby/Rails but that makes perfect sense. Cheers